# wordpress query menu all children of top level parent

Tags: wordpress, menu, parent-child

I'm lost :) I tried many solutions byt I failed. I need to write the code to create menu of all children of current main (top level) parent. Pages structure looks like this:

- Homepage
- Page A

  - Subpage A1
  - Subpage A2

    - Sub-subpage A2-1
    - Sub-subpage A2-2
- Page B

  - Subpage B1
  - Subpage B2

    - Sub-subpage B2-1
    - Sub-subpage B2-2
  - Subpage B3
- Subpage C

So, if I'm on Page A **or** Subpage A2 **or** Subpage A2-1 ... i want to list the same elements:

- Subpage A1
- Subpage A2

  - Sub-subpage A2-1
  - Sub-subpage A2-2

All children of current top level parent (Page A), doesn't metter how 'deep' we're. Any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
<?php
    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
        $root=count($ancestors)-1;
        $parent = $ancestors[$root];
    } else {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    wp_list_pages('orderby=name&depth=4&order=DESC&show_count=0&child_of='.$parent.'&title_li=');
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```