# Find children of a most top level parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

There are similar question asking how to find the top level parent of a child ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519227/find-all-children-of-top-parent-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169281/retrieve-top-level-parent-mysql) and this). I have a similar question but I want to find all childern of a top level parent. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934893/wordpress-query-menu-all-children-of-top-level-parent) is similar question but uses wordpress predefined functions.

sample table:

```
id    parent
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     4
```

I want to select ID with most top parent equals 1. The output should be 3 and all children of 3 I mean (5,6) and even more deep level children if available.

I know I can select them using **two times of inner join** but the hirearchy may be more complex with more levels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple "Recursive CTE" will do what you want:

```
with n as (
  select id from my_table where id = 1 -- starting row(s)
  union all
  select t.id
    from n
    join my_table t on t.parent_id = n.id
)
select id from n;
```

This CTE will go down all levels *ad infinitum*. Well... by default SQL Server limits it to 128 levels (that you can increase to 65k).

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't climbing the entire ladder...

```
select *
from YourTable
where parent = (select top 1 parent from YourTable group by parent order by count(parent) desc)
```

If you were wanting to return the parent of 3, since 3 was listed most often, then you'd use a recursive CTE.

Comment: Thanks, But this returen all parents of a certain child. I need all children of a certain parent. Other answer seems working.